# Is it possible to reset an array without looping through it?

Tags: smart-contract-wallets, solidity-0.8.x

I recently started the Solidity/JS course on FreeCodeCamp.

In the lesson we are resetting an array of addresses to 0 / nul, and it is expressed as below:

```
    for (uint256 funderIndex = 0; funderIndex < funders.length; funderIndex++){
        address funder = funders[funderIndex];
        addressOfFunders[funder] = 0;
    }
    funders = new address[](0);
```

I was wondering if it was possible just to use 'funders = new address' to reset the array ? And if not, why is the loop important ?

Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do the last line (i.e. `funders = new address[](0);`) to reset the all array.

But to me, that for loop is mostly meant to reset a mapping named " addressOfFunders", that, i'm only guessing, is a mapping from address to uint.

The line `address funder = funders[funderIndex];` is only meant to find each address that have provided funds, and the next line `addressOfFunders[funder] = 0;` resets the mapping to 0.

Once all the addresses have been retrieved and all mapping values have been reset to 0, then and only then does your code nukes the array of addresses by doing `funders = new address[](0);`

Am I correct to assume that `addressOfFunders` is a mapping(address => uint)?

Hope this help!

Comment: Thank you, the addressOfFunders is indeed a mapping(address => uint) ! And it's right that it has to be reset as well ! It makes everything clearer ;)